# Java serialization security issues (fail customer's security standards )

Tags: java, security, serialization, reverse-shell, java-sealed-type

I work in a small softwarecompany , we use an agent installed locally which runs on OSGI env to collect data about servers and send them to the main server using ws hhtp request.
Usually we use **sbe protocol** to encode/decode messages , but it does not work for messages > 50M (main server get stuck on sbe decoding), *so for this particular case I send the Java serialized object athat will be deserialized server-side*.
A big customer before installing tested massively our app and it detected the following:

> The /resource/save-data-upload-big-file is vulnerable
> to an unsecure java deserialization.
>
> We succeed to exploit this vulnerability to get an
> execution on the server.
> [image]

It's not clear to me how they managed to do that (**Remot Code execution**) but they proposed to use another method to transmit data collected to server.

I was thinking about **SealedObject**... Will be it safe regarding **RCE**?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

They are right - (java) deserialization issues are a big pain for the industry right now. It even made to be mentioned on [OWASP Top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A8_2017-Insecure_Deserialization). It is not only Java related. Programming languages tend to have some kind of hook mechanism (`readObject`, `writeObject` in Java) that can be misused into calling some internal functions over gadgets and libraries present in the application.

The mitigation is [rather tricky and may force you to go in directions you would rather not want to](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Deserialization_Cheat_Sheet.html). The easiest solution may be to drop the vulnerable endpoint and replace it with something that does not require deserialization of java classes.